# moving a conda environment to an air gapped system

Tags: anaconda, offline

I'm looking for a way to move a conda environment to a machine that will not be able to download any packages or updates.  is there a way that I can move an anaconda env so that it has everything on it that it will need to setup the packages that are part of the environment without an internet connection?  file size is not an issue (cd's are cheap).

Comment: You may find `constructor` interesting: https://www.continuum.io/blog/developer-blog/introducing-constructor

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should have an Internet-connected 'clone' of your target environment. It can be kept updated and it is much easier to install than running around with pendrives and (worse still) CDs.

Then - if your platform is e.g. Linux x86_64, then the `anaconda3` directory in your `$HOME` is actually portable - you can sync it to the target machine and it should 'just work'. This is what we have done for some time.

If it's not a true air gap, but just an isolated network, sometimes the `anaconda3` directory can be mounted e.g. via `sshfs`, and updated from the Internet-connected access machine.

Recenlty we found this:
https://conda.github.io/conda-pack/

- this is an utility to dump a whole conda environment, with its packages, into a single archive file, which can be deployed on the isolated system.